# Change Transactional Propagation for a class while running unit test in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

I have a class A annotated with Transactional propagation requires new

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation = REQUIRES_NEW)
public class A implements B{ 


}
```

Is it possible to change the transactional propagation when running the unit test to something like

```
@Component
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public class A implements B{ 


}
```

Something that comes in my mind to have two classes which implements B, one to use for unit test with propagation required.

Maybe a ugly way to use, looking for something better options.